# Powerbank and Pi overheating?

Tags: hardware, temperature

I'm planning to build a "mobile pi", including a **powerbank** for power supply. These parts are put into a closed case with **no air flow** in it (wooden case with cloth around it).
I don't think the Pi itself would take damage, but I'm affraid that the heat of the Pi might cause the powerbank to take damage/explode/leak etc.

*Question:* Is it likely that the heat causes big damage to the powerbank? Or should I include a fan for cooling?

Comment: Cooling is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The power bank shoudn't get hot. The raspberry pis core is a pretty small square. As you said there is no ventilation. If possible, place the power bank on top of the older box and feed the cable into the box.

Comment: An external powerwank won't be possible for my project. My Idea would be to use a fann to cool the Pi, so the heat doesnt stay in the case. Or is it never a good idea to keep a powerbank in a closed case?

Comment: Test run the mobile pi. Check if the power bank is hot after a while. If it is, add two fans to the box, one to insert air, and one to remove hot air.

Comment: Wouldnt one fan be enough? But ok thanks :)

Comment: If you are using one fan, I think it would be best to draw air out of the box to remove warm air from accumulating. I don't know how noisy it would be but if it doesn't work out for you, just switch it over to push air in.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help anyone with my knowledge I have learned.